# Compress APK for smaller file size

Tags: android, cordova, apk

The apk file size for my app is quite big. Is it possible to reduce the file size by using better compression level or different compression engine such as lzma (https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/native-library-compression-sdk-for-android-apps)?

Comment: Have you used `Google play apk expansion` lib? The one more option would be APK Splits http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits

Comment: Are you already using minification & resource shrinking?

Comment: @fractalwrench I am just follow standard step for creating APK file. Using `jarsigner` and `zipalign`.

Comment: why is your apk so big? embedded video/audio/high-res-images? using fat libs? many classes?

Comment: @k3b Because I am using crosswalk in my project. Therefore, the APK file is about 21MB. Without it (crosswalk), it will be only about 1-2MB. So, I am thinking to use some compression method to get it smaller a bit.

Answer (score 3):

To simply answer your question:

Yes, use lzma.

Okay, now some other recommendations.

1. **Build in release mode.** This is very important, as the app size when built in debug mode can be a lot bigger than when built in release mode.
2. Compress your images. Often when making an app you don't really look at the size of images, and they usually tend to be the main issue concerning size. Simply opening them in, let's say paint.net, and saving them again with lower quality can help a lot.
3. Compress your audio files. Load them up in audacity and export them as MP3 with lower quality.

These are some small recommendations of mine. If you need your apk to be smaller still, I'd suggest trying [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=shrink%20apk%20size)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to use lzma? All I know is standard procedure to create APK file.

Comment: Debug mode app size is depend on what you have configured in build.gradle. If you configure same for both debug and release mode like `buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled true } debug {minifyEnabled true } }` then there won't be any size changes in both the build apk

Comment: @user1995781 LZMA is an algorythm, and I'm not very knowledgeable about it. It's not a program, nor as far as I know a feature you can tick on. It seems to be more like zipping your .apk.  I'd suggest googling on it.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar Thank you. After trying with your method, now my APK file size is reduced from 21MB to 17MB.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar Unfortunately, the after install the compressed APK, the app does not work. It exit instantly with error message when running the app.

Comment: @user1995781 minify will do compress your apk into small size. You need to alter your proguard based on the need. Good guidance is available in https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Crosswalk Lite](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Crosswalk-Project-Lite), Which is a slim version of Crosswalk, with less features, but keeping the great performance.

The project still doesn't have a stable version ( Still in Canary channel ) to be used for production like normal Crosswalk.

I think Crosswalk Lite will be a great solution for problems like Yours, maybe in the near future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about crosswalk lite. As you know, it's not as stable and as up to date as normal crosswalk. Therefore, it is not my main choice.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @JaiprakashSoni, I'm going to modify my answer to include more information about Crosswalk Lite

Comment: I agree with You @user1995781, Just shared what I think may help, event not in the current time.